# Error en Cast to ObjectID

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Buenas:

Parto del siguiente esquema:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: ObjectId
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Title required']
    },

    students:[{
        id : ObjectId,
        name: String,
        email: {
            type: String,
            validate: {
                validator: function(value) {
                    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(value);
                },
                message: 'Invalid email address'
            }
        }
    }]
})
```

La semilla que creo en primera instancia es:

```
{
    "title" : "3",
    "students" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "admin",
            "name" : "admin",
            "email" : "admin@admin.es"
         }
     ]
   }
```

A la hora de añadir nuevos elementos lo intento por ejemplo (obviamente bien escrito esto está sacado del debug),con:

```
debug: [service] Post Query title=2, students=[id=manolo, email=manolo@gmail.com, name=manolo]
```

Quiero añadir unos estudiantes en concreto, que lo cojo de otra colección, y necesito el mismo id porque luego los utilizo para comparar, búsquedas, etc.
Cada vez que intento añadir un estudiante, me dice el siguiente error:

```
Data model:  strictMode=true, selected=undefined, shardval=undefined, saveError=undefined, message=Cast to ObjectID failed for value "superadmin" at path "id", 
name=CastError, stringValue="manolo", kind=ObjectID, value=manolo, path=id, message=Cast to ObjectId failed for value "manolo" at path "id"
```

He probado previamente a castear por el id con mongoose.Type.ObjectId, y me sigue dando error.

La función para guardar es simple:

```
(...)
var myQuery = {
          title: body.title,            
          students : body.students
        };
var newData= new model(myQuery);
Logger.debug('Data model: ',newData);
newData.save(function(error, data){
         (...)
```

Y al hacer el new model(..), es cuando me "peta" y ya me sale el error, por tanto nunca llega al save.

Si intento hacer el casting antes de crear la instancia del model, me salta un error diferente. Pero es que le estoy pasando el ID de otra colección, es imposible que sea diferente:

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters at new ObjectID
```

Comment: creo que te falta la conversion var mid = new Mongo.ObjectID(tustring);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El diseño de tus modelos no es correcto y no es muy trabajable en situaciones reales. En primer lugar esos atributos `id` son inservibles porque MongoDB te genera `_id` automáticamente para cada documento.

MongoDB te permite mantener referencias y Mongoose te ayuda mucho en esto gracias a sus métodos para hacer una especie de `join` de las referencias.

Deberías crear un modelo `Student`:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
});
```

Y en tu modelo principal **referenciar** a este modelo:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Title required']
  },
  students:[{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Student',
  }],
});
```

De modo que los `_id` de los estudiantes sean guardados en los documentos principales. Al seleccionarlos, [mongoose](/questions/tagged/mongoose) te permite *popular* esos documentos trayendo los documentos de las referencias:

```
Student.find().populate('students');
```

Esto hará una especie de `INNER JOIN` para obtener tanto los documentos principales como los estudiantes.